# Understanding defining and non-defining relative clauses in the context of mathematics

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

I am a student of mathematics and I have to write my thesis in English. A problem which occurs very often is the distinction between defining and non-defining relative clauses. In mathematics, this appears mostly in situations where one needs to define things. I know assume that I would need to use the defining clause in definitions (as one would guess by the word "definition"). However, some people correct my phrases, which is quite confusing. Therefore, I would like to clear this up with you.

Let us go through an easy example. **Which of the following sentences are correct for making a mathematical assumption or a definition?**

1. Let c be an integer which is divisible by 2. Then c is an even
   number.
2. Let c be an integer, which is divisible by 2. Then c is an
   even number.

I would assume that the first one is correct because the fact that c is divisible by 2 is essential for the statement. If we would omit "which is divisible by 2", then the statement is clearly wrong.

Could you please tell me if my line of reasoning is correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The first one is the restrictive relative clause and it's appropriate for a definition. A non-restrictive relative as in the second example is bizarre - why mention irrelevant matters in a definition? It's like putting a definition of _prime_ into the definition of the Zeta function.

Comment: The second is simply wrong. It's similar to saying "Let c be an integer, therefore c is divisible by 2". Adding the comma makes it a parenthetical comment, not a restrictive clause.

Comment: Could you find a more helpful translator? I mean that although what you say makes some sense, it doesn't really work… which is very likely part of the problem.

Comment: I suggest that neither in English nor in maths is there any useful difference in meaning between your examples

If 'an integer which is…' or 'an integer, which is…' or even 'an integer divisible…' show any significant differences, what are they?